# kubernetes Deployment PodName setting

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, kubernetes-deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: test_ml_server:2.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: hostpath-vol-testserver
              mountPath: /app/test/api
#          env:
#            - name: POD_NAME
#              valueFrom:
#                fieldRef:
#                  fieldPath: template.metadata.name
        - name: testdb
          image: test_db:1.4
          ports:
            - name: testdb
              containerPort: 1433
          volumeMounts:
            - name: hostpath-vol-testdb
              mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
#          env:
#            - name: POD_NAME
#              valueFrom:
#                fieldRef:
#                  fieldPath: template.metadata.name
      volumes:
        - name: hostpath-vol-testserver
          hostPath:
            path: /usr/testhostpath/testserver
        - name: hostpath-vol-testdb
          hostPath:
            path: /usr/testhostpath/testdb
```

I want to set the name of the pod Because it communicates internally based on the name of the pod
but when a pod is created, it cannot be used because the variable name is appended to the end.
How can I set the pod name?

Comment: Usually you'd deploy a corresponding Service, and connect to the Service, which will forward requests to one of the matching Pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you use, `statefulset` instead of `deployment`. Statefulset's pod name will be like `<statefulsetName-0>`,`<statefulsetName-1>`... And you will need a `clusterIP` service. with which you can bound your pods. see the doc for more details. [Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-svc
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: test
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: test-StatefulSet
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: test-svc
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: test_ml_server:2.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: hostpath-vol-testserver
              mountPath: /app/test/api
        - name: testdb
          image: test_db:1.4
          ports:
            - name: testdb
              containerPort: 1433
          volumeMounts:
            - name: hostpath-vol-testdb
              mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
      volumes:
        - name: hostpath-vol-testserver
          hostPath:
            path: /usr/testhostpath/testserver
        - name: hostpath-vol-testdb
          hostPath:
            path: /usr/testhostpath/testdb
```

Here, The pod name will be like this `test-StatefulSet-0`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the `kind: Deployment` it won't be possible ideally in this scenario you can use `kind: Statefulset`.

Instead of POD to POD communication, you can use the Kubernetes **service** for communication.

Still, statefulset manage the pod name in the sequence

```
statefulsetname - 0
statefulsetname - 1
statefulsetname - 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

It is the property of the pods of a `Deployment` that they do not have an identity associated with them.

You could have a look at [`Statefulset`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) instead of a Deployment if you want the pods to have a state.

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/):

> Like a Deployment, a StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an
> identical container spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains
> a sticky identity for each of their Pods. These pods are created from
> the same spec, but are not interchangeable: each has a persistent
> identifier that it maintains across any rescheduling.

So, if you have a `Statefulset` object named `myapp` with two replicas, the pods will be named as `myapp-0` and `myapp-1`.